# NTLDR is missing

Tags: system-installation

I'm new with Ubuntu.

I have formatted my HDD and tried to install Ubuntu from a DVD, but I only get the above mentioned message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is happening because your BIOS is still trying to boot from local hard disk and is unable to find boot loader.

You should go to BIOS settings and change first boot device to CD/DVD drive and then try rebooting again.

To go to BIOS settings, start your machine and keep tapping either of F2, Del or F8 keys. These keys may or may not be different depending on manufacturer. But for most of the laptops, F2 works and for desktops, it is Del